# I use three variants of memory clearing. Are all of them safe? Can I get memory leaks?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I use "placement new" for allocation of my object. And I use three variants of memory clearing. Are all of them safe? Can I get memory leaks?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <vector>
using namespace ::std;

class A{
private:
    double x;
public:
    A() : x(0) { cout << "A class; ptr: " << this << " created." << endl; } 
    ~A() { cout << "A class; ptr: " << this << " destroyed." << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
try{
    // 1. Creating of object in the necessary memory address

    static_assert(sizeof(char) == 1, "Unexpected size of char.");
    int x = -1; // Variants of memory clearing
    while (x < 0 || x > 2) {
        cout << "Variant (0,1,2): ";
        cin >> x;
    }
    char* p = new char[sizeof(A)]; // some memory area...

    A* a = new(p)A(); // Place my object in the 'p' address.

    // Here is my basic work to do...

    // Now I must to free my memory:
    if(!x){ // First variant
        delete a;           
    }
    else if (x == 1){ // Second variant
        delete reinterpret_cast<A*>(p); 
    }
    else if (x == 2){ // Third variant
        a->~A();        
        delete[] p; 
    }
    else{
        throw runtime_error("Invalid variant!");
    }
    a = nullptr;
    p = nullptr;

    cout << endl;   
}
catch(exception& e){
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    return 1;
}
catch(...){
    cerr << "Unknown exception." << endl;
    return 2;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: When your question simply repeats the title it often means that you haven't been descriptive enough :p Maybe explain your three variants (I know that your code is short, but still, it helps)

Comment: You should **never** call destructors explicitely! They will be called automatically when the instance goes out of scope or delete is called.

Comment: `char` is required to be 1 byte long by the standard, the assertion is redundant.

Comment: @g-makulik You need to call the destructor when using placement new.

Comment: You normally use placement `new` to decouple allocation from construction, and destruction from deallocation. As such, your third in the only one that really makes much sense. The other two look legal as well, but if they'll work for you, raise question about whether you should have used placement `new` at all.

Comment: Why to use placement new in the 1st case? (but @NeilKirk is right of course).

Comment: @H2CO3, ok. I wrote it because I read in the book, it is implementation-defined. This book: http://www.amazon.com/The-Programming-Language-4th-Edition/dp/0321563840/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1380881727&sr=8-1&keywords=stroustrup

Comment: @Bush The book probably says the size of a byte is implementation defined. sizeof(char) will be 1 in any case.

Comment: My pointers point at the same memory address. It is Forbid to call delete\delete[] twice for the same pointer (it is authorized only for nullptr). I called the delete for my pointer. And I call my destructor manually, when the delete operator ain't call its.

Answer (score 3):

The variant with `delete[]` and explicit destructor call is the correct one since it is a mirror reflection of how you allocated/constructed it:

```
char* p = new char[sizeof(A)];
A* a = new(p)A();
...
a->~A();        
delete[] p;
```

But if you don't have really good reason to use the placement new, consider simple and straightforward:

```
A* a = new A();
...
delete a;
```

And although `delete` should be called for every `new` and `delete[]` for every `new[]`, since you allocated an array of `char`s, the second option doesn't seem to be very reasonable, however still legal (as long as you are sure that the size of the memory block is really equal to `sizeof(A)` and there is a valid object of type `A` that resides within this array):

```
char* p = new char[sizeof(A)];
delete reinterpret_cast<A*>(p);
```

---

Also note that the following line is completely useless:

```
static_assert(sizeof(char) == 1, "Unexpected size of char.");
```

since it is guaranteed by the standard that `sizeof(char)` always returns 1.

Comment: >avoid doing it and simply do...
I know. My question is about other.

Comment: >It is important to know that delete should be called for every new and delete[] for every new[]. If you use new[] and then try to free this memory using delete...

I know. My pointers point at the same memory address. Forbid to call delete\delete[] twice for the same pointer.

Comment: @Bush: There 2nd option relies on 2 facts: 1. the size of chunk of the memory that `p` points to is equal to `sizeof(A)` and 2. a valid object is stored within this memory so that the appropriate destructor will be called.

Answer (score 1):

The third variant is the correct way to delete the object and clear the memory you have allocated.